# Statically installing Qt4 such that OpenCV can detect the installed Qt4 libraries

Tags: qt, opencv, cmake, compilation, cross-compiling

I am currently using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

How can I statically build Qt 4.8.5 -

https://download.qt.io/archive/qt/4.8/4.8.5/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.5.tar.gz

such that when I cmake OpenCV 2.4.13 -

https://github.com/opencv/opencv/archive/2.4.13.zip

it correctly identifies the location of Qt4 ?

When I cmake OpenCV after I have installed Qt4 in `/usr/local/qt4-static/`, the `find_package(Qt4 REQUIRED QtCore QtGui QtTest)` function call within `opencv-2.4.13/cmake/OpenCVFindLibsGUI.cmake` fails because it cannot find `qmake`. Also, upon running the `qmake -query` in the terminal, Ubuntu says that qmake is not installed, when it clearly in `/usr/local/qt4-static/`.

How should I go about this so OpenCV `cmake` correctly recognizes Qt4 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Build Qt

Extract the source-code and run `./configure && make` and then `sudo make install`. It should create all necessary configuration to run qmake in any folder (system-wide).

2. **Additional**: create a symlink/export (**use only if make install did not work for you**)

You need to promote qmake to `$PATH` or create a symlink, **but this is usually done when you run `sudo make install`** after `make` in the Qt source-folder.

```
root:/home# echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:
```

**Symlink** (permanently)

```
ln -s /path/to/qmake /usr/sbin/qmake
```

or

**export** (temporary)

```
export PATH=$PATH:/folder/of/qmake
```

Afterwards qmake -v is working whereever you are

```
root:/tmp qmake -v
QMake version 3.1
Using Qt version 5.10.1 in /usr/local/Qt-5.10.1/lib
```

If your project still cannot determine the location of Qt, read the pro/pri/cmake file to understand how it looks for the path.

Comment: That worked for me - the `sudo make install` did not generate the symlink.